# How to make node.on("close") synchronous in nodered?

Tags: node-red

I'm doing async job in `node.on("close")` and I do not want other `node.on("close")` func to start executing. In my code it prints here1 here1 here2 here2 since I have 2 same node in my flow. When I delete both of them and press deploy, they both enter `node.on("close")` in same time but I want them to wait each other. How can I make the output here1 here2 here1 here2?

```js
node.on("close", async (removed, done) => {
    if (removed) {
        console.log("here1");
        try {
            await utils.deletePlcOption(node);
        } catch (err) {
            utils.errorHandler(err, node);
        }
        console.log("here2");
    }
    done();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, without implementing your own locking e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore